# При поиске определенного элемента как ответ получаю False, хотя должен получать True Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium

Код ищет по названию акции, её на сайте.
Сам код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def Enable_module(driver, Stocks):
    try:
        Element_Stocks = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sScreenerResultsCont js-stock-screener-results']")
        Search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until((EC.element_to_be_clickable(Element_Stocks.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, Stocks))))
        return True
    except:
        return False

def Replace_module(iterable):
    
    STR_1 = "//a[@onclick='stockScreenerPaginationClick(2)']"
    New_String = STR_1.replace("2", str(iterable))
    return New_String

def Searching_module(driver, Stocks):
    
    # Getting the number of elements
    Count_element = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='pagination']"))

    CE = range(Count_element + 1)

    for i in CE:
        
        Search = Enable_module(driver, Stocks)

        print('Да чи нет ?', Search)
        if Search == True:
            Element_Stocks = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sScreenerResultsCont js-stock-screener-results']")
            Searching = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until((EC.element_to_be_clickable(Element_Stocks.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, Stocks)))).click()

            Web_App_Site = driver.current_url()
            return Web_App_Site
            break
        else:
            Find_Swicher = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='paginationWrap']")
            iterable = i + 2
            Module_Replacer = Replace_module(iterable)
            
            Swicher = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until((EC.element_to_be_clickable(Find_Swicher.find_element(By.XPATH, Module_Replacer))))
            Swicher.click()




def Parser():
    # Driver, with open URl address 
    URL = 'https://ru.investing.com/stock-screener/?sp=country::56|sector::a|industry::a|equityType::a|exchange::40%3Ceq_market_cap;1'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\nasta\Desktop\Parcer\Chrome_Driver\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get(URL)

    # Wait
    driver.implicitly_wait(1)

    # Open TMP file Stocks.txt
    with open(r"C:\Users\nasta\Desktop\Parcer\TMP\Stocks.txt") as file:
        Stocks = file.readline()

    # Searching module
    Web_App_Site = Searching_module(driver, Stocks)
    print(Web_App_Site)
```

Момент где у меня выходт не правильный ответ, при поиске selenium должен на 2 странице выдавать True (P.S. ищу акцию сбера), но выдает False
Тот самый момент:

```
def Enable_module(driver, Stocks):
    try:
        Element_Stocks = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sScreenerResultsCont js-stock-screener-results']")
        Search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until((EC.element_to_be_clickable(Element_Stocks.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, Stocks))))
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Comment: Может вы сможете объяснить смысл селениума? Вот люди слепо ставят его, не понимая, что он создан для тестирования, а не парсинга. Тянут в свой проект целый браузер! И ради чего? Не понятно... Вот взять ваш сайт, открываем "средства разработчика" (обычно F12), заходим на сайт, видим [простой POST запрос](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUG7p.png), получаем [огромный набор данных](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouSHJ.png), в виде JSON. Я не знаю как на питоне, но в C# отправить POST и десериализовать JSON - строки 3 кода, без HTML парсинга, браузера и др. Подумайте, правильную ли вы "тактику" выбрали...

Comment: Если False, значит ошибка. Но ошибку в Exept вы не выводите. Уберите Try, посмотрите на чем падаете.